# How do I get a wordpress container to work behind an NGINX reverse proxy

Tags: wordpress, apache, docker, nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

Wondering if anybody else has similar issues with Docker wordpress containers. I'm not confident in my apache/wordpress abilities. Maybe somebody here can help.

Trying to setup the standard wordpress docker container behind an nginx reverse proxy using ssl.

All my other apps work fine, it's only worpress/apache with the issue.

My NGINX default.conf:

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name example.com;
        return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;
}
########## ADDED
upstream app-a {
    server example.com:2368;
}

upstream app-b {
    server example.com:8080;
}

##########
server {
        listen 443 ssl;
        server_name example.com;
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index index.html index.htm;
        client_max_body_size 10G;
        location / {
                 proxy_pass         http://app-a;
            proxy_redirect     off;
            proxy_set_header   Host $host;
            proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
        }

location = /press {
                return 301 https://example.com:8443;
        }


        ssl on;
        ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem;
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers On;
        ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
        ssl_ciphers ECDH+AESGCM:DH+AESGCM:ECDH+AES256:DH+AES256:ECDH+AES128:DH+AES:ECDH+3DES:DH+3DES:RSA+AESGCM:RSA+AES:RSA+3DES:!aNULL:!MD5:!DSS;
}


server {
        listen 8443 ssl;

        server_name example.com;

        #root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        root /var/www/html/press;
        index index.php index.html index.htm;
        client_max_body_size 10G;

        location / {
                proxy_pass         http://app-b;
            proxy_redirect     off;
            proxy_set_header   Host $host;
            proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
        }


        ssl on;
        ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem;

        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers On;
        ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
        ssl_ciphers ECDH+AESGCM:DH+AESGCM:ECDH+AES256:DH+AES256:ECDH+AES128:DH+AES:ECDH+3DES:DH+3DES:RSA+AESGCM:RSA+AES:RSA+3DES:!aNULL:!MD5:!DSS;

}
```

How I'm starting my wordpress container:

```
docker run -d --name mywordpress --link mytestsql:mysql -v mypressvol:/var/www/html -e WORDPRESS_DB_USER=root -e WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD=secret -p 8080:80 wordpress
```

When I run the WP setup I get language selection but no graphics and shows not secure in the address bar. However If I go to 8080 in my browser the app works just fine, but no ssl.  Like I said all my other apps work fine with this.  It's only WordPress giving me fits. Any ideas?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This configurations work fine:

1) Nginx proxy

```
server {
    listen                          80;
    server_name                     example.ru www.example.ru;
    return 301                      https://$server_name$request_uri;
}

 server {
    listen 443;
    server_name example.ru www.example.ru;

    ssl_certificate           /etc/nginx/certs/example.ru.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key       /etc/nginx/certs/example.ru.key;

    ssl on;
    ssl_session_cache  builtin:1000  shared:SSL:10m;
    ssl_protocols  TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers HIGH:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!CAMELLIA:!DES:!MD5:!PSK:!RC4;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://wp_web;
    }
}
```

Don't forget to put them both in one network in docker-compose.yml in order to access the container by service name.

2) Wordpress container. Your host. Apache2 conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
    # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
    # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
    # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
    # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
    # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
    # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.

    ServerName example.ru
    ServerAlias www.example.ru

    SetEnvIf X-Forwarded-Proto https HTTPS=on

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/example

    <Directory /var/www/example>
        Allowoverride All
    </Directory>

    # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
    # error, crit, alert, emerg.
    # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
    # modules, e.g.
    #LogLevel info ssl:warn

    ErrorLog /var/www/example/logs/apache.error.log
    CustomLog /var/www/example/logs/apache.access.log combined_with_x_real_ip

    # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
    # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
    # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
    # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
    # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
    #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Not working for me probably because I'm using multiple apps.

Comment: Tell me what's going on when you use my confs, I'll try to help.